# dump php curl request for debug request with command line later

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way in php_curl to log entre curl request which can later use to run as a command with curl command line utility?

Comment: No. You can't do so in PHP

Comment: That's disappointing

Comment: You can use browser's dev tool such as Firebug instead. It allows to get curl equivalent for any HTTP request

Comment: Yes but my use case is different. I have php proxy setup with curl and want to dump all curl requests it makes in format for curl command line